# Receive error when try to modify content type header

Tags: spring, servlets, httpresponse

In below code I'm attempting to modify the response of the request
using a ResponseEntity . The code below redirects user to displaySheet.jsp

But I am receiving this error :

```
Invalid token character '/' in token "text/html;charset=UTF-8"
```

The code :

```
    @ResourceMapping(value = "display")
    public ResponseEntity<String> displayResult(final ModelMap model,

HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();

        responseHeaders.setContentType(new MediaType("Content-Type", "text/html;charset=UTF-8"));
return new ResponseEntity<String>("displaySheet", responseHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED);

}
```

Is my token incorrect ?

Answer (score 0):

Fix for me is to add javax.portlet.ResourceResponse to method and then set the content type :

```
 @ResourceMapping(value = "display")
    public String displayResult(javax.portlet.ResourceResponse rr)

rr.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

return "mypage"

}
```